# Python: How to convert .ofx file into .csv

Tags: csv, python-3.x, ofx

Does any one know how to convert .ofx file in to .csv file. using python language?

I have a file of bank statement which have .ofx format I want to use it in my personal software which support only .csv format.

Please help.

Comment: use this python library : https://github.com/jseutter/ofxparse

Comment: thanks @MartinV. but this library does not convert it into csv.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but the python package [ofxparse](https://github.com/jseutter/ofxparse/tree/master) can open and read ofx files. From there, you can consult your transactions and export them as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Not python, but [iCreateOFX Basic](http://icreateofx.co.uk/Convert-CSV-to-OFX) can convert both OFX and QIF files to CSV (and the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ofxparse import OfxParser
import csv

with open(r"data\Extrato31232179272.ofx") as fileobj:
    ofx = OfxParser.parse(fileobj)


lst_operacoes = []

for i in ofx.account.statement.transactions:
    lst_operacoes.append(
        {
            "payee": i.payee,
            "type": i.type,
            "date": i.date,
            "user_date": i.user_date,
            "amount": f"{i.amount}".replace(".", ","),
            "id": i.id,
            "memo": i.memo,
            "sic": i.sic,
            "mmc": i.mcc,
            "checksum": i.checknum,
        }
    )


colunas = [
    "payee",
    "type",
    "date",
    "user_date",
    "amount",
    "id",
    "memo",
    "sic",
    "mmc",
    "checksum",
]

# use latin-1 ou iso-8859-1 para windows
# use utf-8 para linux e mac
with open(r"data/extrato.csv", "w", encoding="latin-1", newline="") as filecsv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(filecsv, fieldnames=colunas, dialect="excel")
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lst_operacoes)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).